# 301 Redirect with Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, http-status-code-301

I'm looking for a way to do a 301 redirect on Glassfish, similar to what you could do with a .htaccess file on Apache by writing something like this:

```
redirect 301 /old/old.htm http://www.mydomain.com/new.htm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add a property "redirect_n" in the virtual host.
For example:
Name: redirect_1 
Value: from=/old/old.htm url-prefix=http://www.mydomain.com/new.htm

See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4496/ggjaa/index.html